# error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'some_struct<int>&&' to lvalue of type 'some_struct<int>'

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, rvalue-reference, lvalue

I'm taking a templated rvalue-reference in the function signature which should make it an universal reference. However, lvalues are still not able to bind to this parameter. Check this out:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIA7KQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdFxtrX1jVktCsM9wX3FA2UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQmm25oDGsJBApH2CYaAIJbO3uYh8fIE/io17cP9wSYLASBn%2BrzcBAAnglGKwXgAVV4AEX2wQI33uE2IXgc%2BwUqDYAH0MVjUfcTLErPd9lScXjMISCJiHBB4Ux5j9qRz9iBqUx8WSLPsmIdYgj2dT%2BcLRaTKTyvER9gliCiIPNhRS7pzqYqUVQIOYzAg2rRUIczABWdAmM1uBj60iC/FszbqjlkqW/DXUln4xH7DRHdVugM/H4AegAVPsCAg8Ap9uhUJgFIJ9gB3EgAaxDfwBQKYIKOYMh0LY%2B1haLuTDlJv4qAguIJRIchfLmxuZgAbOYO4LiMBVfyxVS8FR9qcJphVIr9vWCOgQCAFDD8UwrsdYfaUdcB%2BSh5y6sAAHTawQq4MyqlB0ki7N3f6A4EvQsQqHMNiHj9ltc3e5V%2BUROp61pelGVRddv27bsP0PXtgAUHcXWpPUzSsTsrVFXcL05EcxwECcp2IGcPgXJcCVXFsFE3QRtzVPdNSpA8FGPJVTydRDNSvT1LxFFV7WgtiQxvaU7nDUNb3vPMC2OF8SzhCs/xrVA6wbOkmzAtxW3bHsDwQvccPHf4CKIucSOXcj1yosDsF0rCOQPZjlQErDOJcnMH3zJ9pOLN9MGgr95OrfYAOIIDGwZYkKO%2BTs/MYmyuJnK1UK7M0MPY7DRwMydp1nedFzMtcNMo5FqLbOL6P3PsmJPAgz2dOjxSE%2BK3V4/Z%2BPPB5GtvFF9hYJhghVWjhI5FSQOJfYaGICZ%2BS4IM6qwka1JxSoBEtckzFmtKFvC7FozwYhVosMAOGQI6Nr3LbQPG5Z6gQflwswM6hupWtqD2iYnI9DlgvrZaGHQUhdv2mQVmjD63Q4RZaE4M1eD8DgtFIVBODcaxrBpFY1lNTYeABzQIcWDMQEkWJD2xjRYg0SQAE4Ow0AAOTYzTNFooY4SRYbxxHOF4BQQA0XH4Yh0g4FgGBEBQPEEjoaJyEoNBAWlmI4OYBIFAQVACD4Oh/kmygIk5iJgjqcFOBx%2BW2EEAB5BhaBNwXSCwXqjHEe38GISpHAANyTTnJ0qOV1gRlE2k52g8AiYhjY8LBOYZPAWFNoWqAMOCADU8EwVNLdfROZEEEQxHYKQ8/kJQ1E53QWcMYxUcsfRw95yBFlQC40l5jgAFoAHUxFofYO8tuMO47j4jgRUxLGsMwEYqKpnAgVxRmaUhAmmIoSmyZJUgEJfN9yNJenXuZWnaapJl38Y2g9s/ukP/pSiGboL8f%2Bo79mUpFlxDGi4B931h4SG0MOb2yRhwVQdMOwdw7JIfYwBkDIBnOFBgGZVQQBRpPOu%2BxcCEBIFjFo%2BwPAK3oIRLYXB5i8AIHjeYixDRMCwDEXirN2akATmafmcMEagJ5nzAWWhFgi3FssAgCQ5SywgPLKWxDQgwk4OAyB0DYHwP2FwMwh4zC8EwPgIgSp5wtH4PnUQ4hi76NLiodQ9tK6kFTJHBIidAEcBhqQDhvBQGWzlCIgg%2BxUCjjkVAmBcCEEQCQSgmchDJHRDweQ3h%2BNSCEzYfoTgzDWHsM5lw2wPDKGC2obEkAZpVEdjplTMwVM2GbCplwaBkg6ZmgSRwTYwDOHc2idk1m6inGpKaZkvhixvaTTSETIAA%3D)

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T = int>
struct some_struct
{
    some_struct(T a)
        :   a_{ a }
    { }

    auto print() {
        printf("hello %d\n", a_);
    }

    T a_ = 0;
};

/* this doesnt work

template <typename T>
auto foo(some_struct<T>&& arg) {
    if constexpr (std::same_as<T, int>) {
        arg.print();
    }
}

template <typename... Ts>
auto bar(some_struct<Ts>&&... args) {
    ([&]{
        if constexpr (std::same_as<Ts, int>) {
            args.print();
        }
    }(), ...);
}

*/

template <typename T>
auto foo(some_struct<T>& arg) {
    if constexpr (std::same_as<T, int>) {
        arg.print();
    }
}

template <typename... Ts>
auto bar(some_struct<Ts>&... args) {
    ([&]{
        if constexpr (std::same_as<Ts, int>) {
            args.print();
        }
    }(), ...);
}


int main() {

    some_struct first{1};
    some_struct second{2};
    some_struct third{'c'};
    some_struct fourth{true};

    foo(first);

    bar(second,third,fourth);
}
```

Yields:

```
<source>:58:9: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'some_struct<int>&&' to lvalue of type 'some_struct<int>'
   58 |     foo(first);
      |         ^~~~~
<source>:19:27: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'auto foo(some_struct<T>&&) [with T = int]'
   19 | auto foo(some_struct<T>&& arg) {
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
<source>:60:9: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'some_struct<int>&&' to lvalue of type 'some_struct<int>'
   60 |     bar(second,third,fourth);
      |         ^~~~~~
<source>:26:27: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'auto bar(some_struct<Ts>&& ...) [with Ts = {int, char, bool}]'
   26 | auto bar(some_struct<Ts>&&... args) {
```

Comment: The demo compiles, even if you uncomment out the code that says it doesn't work. Is the intent that _only_ the commented out code is used, and the rest of the code is removed? If so, can you provide an example that directly demonstrates the problem you're having,  so that I don't have to figure out how to manipulate it to get there?

Comment: Also there are no "universal references" (prefer forwarding reference, it's a better term) in this example. `some_struct<T>&&` is an rvalue reference, and `some_struct<Ts>&&...` is a pack of rvalue references. A forwarding reference is only the special case of `T&&` where `T` is a template parameter.

Comment: @Barry When you comment out the code that works and uncomment the code with && it doesn't work. But then again it makes sense what you say, that the other version is just a pack of rvalue references.